# Finding ORACLE_SID for database?

Tags: sql, oracle10g

Is there any way to find out which SID belongs to which database in Oracle database, by executing sql query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check it out:

```
select instance from v$thread

select distinct sid from v$mystat

select * from global_name
```

Comment: SQL> select instance from v$thread;
SP2-0640: Not connected